# Trying to clean up my MVC3 code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some MVC3 Razor code. I am not so familiar with Razor but I can understand what the code is doing. I would like to clean this code up. Is there anything that could be done or is what I have the best possible?

```
@{ var i=1; foreach (var topic in @Model.Topic)
   {
    <option value="@topic.RowKey">@(i++). @topic.Description</option>
   }
}
```

Comment: Personally I find your code easier to read than what @casperOne suggested since I don't have to think to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd merge the selection of the index of the item with the item in the sequence while iterating, like so:

```
@{ foreach (var topic in @Model.Topic.
        Select((t, i) => new { Topic = t, Index = i + 1}))
   {
    <option value="@topic.RowKey">@(topic.Index). 
        @topic.Topic.Description</option>
   }
}
```

This way, you don't have separation the indexing logic from the topic, it's all contained neatly within the anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like options for a select list, in which case you might want to be using the built-in `@Html.SelectList` bits rather than looping through things and writing a string.